# Aptitude & Yum: Studies on Actual Security

Tags: opensource, vulnerability-assessment

The theory has long been that package managers (and potentially other sources of FOSS) were potentially "more secure" and/or "more trustworthy" than commercial software because more people's eyes have been on the code and there are more people finding issues.

Have any major security companies done and published a full study of the actual security differences between these software source, to include things like the rate at which bugs are found and the rate at which those [major] bugs are fixed?

Comment: While I am not aware of any specific studies done by major companies, it's possible that your question can be answered by https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4441/165253