# What countries have strong data protection laws?

Tags: legal

Many answers on this site and other security-related websites state that one should host sensitive data in [a country with strong data protection laws](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93028/4758). **What countries are these, and how is this determined?**

I understand that Germany has [an excellent webhosting service](https://www.hetzner.de/) as does [the UK](https://exascale.co.uk/). **Are either of these countries considered to have strong data protection laws?** Even if they do, is it reasonable to assume that those laws are abided by?

Comment: Closing as the answer to this will change from year to year. And since it is more of a legal question, it's off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a [website](http://dlapiperdataprotection.com/#handbook/world-map-section/c1_MT) which list a overview of the key privacy and data protection laws and regulations across 77 different jurisdictions. Of course i haven't read the legislation of any of these countries and i'm not a lawyer so you should pick one of this countries and do a deep search to see if their laws suit your needs.

And laws can change at any time this should not be the end of your search but rather the start for a more deep and current search on the law.

[image]

Comment: Man, why would they color "good" as red, and "bad" as green?

Comment: I don't know lol. But red = heavy regulation & enforcement and green = limited regulation or enforcement

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search turned up the [following](http://nomadcapitalist.com/2013/12/15/top-5-best-countries-host-website-data-privacy/):

- Romania
- Switzerland
- Netherlands
- Norway
- Iceland